# Json-schema - How to verify that a specific element is not in an array?

Tags: arrays, jsonschema

I’ve got a list of accounts (accountId, currency,  accountType)

Id1 , USD, Account /
Id2, GBP, Account /
Id3 , EUR, Account /
Id4 , NOK, Account

When I do the call to the api to get a list of accounts, I want to make sure that the accountid = 3 is not in the results. How can I achieve this? This is my schema:

```
    {
  "title": "Acc schema",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "account": {
      "properties": {
        "accountId": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1,
          "maxLength": 15
        },
        "currency": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 3,
          "maxLength": 3
        },
        "accountType": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            ”Account”
          ]
        }
      },
      "required": ["accountId"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "data": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "accounts": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/account"
              }
            ],
            "additionalItems": false
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/data"
    },
    "headers": {
      "type": "object"
    },
    "config": {
      "type": "object"
    },
    "request": {
      "type": "object"
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "statusText": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main keywords would be `not` and `contains`.

Your `data` entry in the `definitions` could look like this then (also without the unnecessary `anyOf`):

```
    "data": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "accounts": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/account"
          },
          “not”: {
            “contains”: {
              “type”: “object”,
              “properties”: {
                “accountId”: {
                  “const”: “3”
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
```

Comment: If this answered your question, feel free to mark it as “accepted” via the tick mark on the left. That way, others won’t spend time on providing alternative answers unnecessarily.